# como inserir 2 destinatários diferentes para envio de formulário

Tags: php, email

Preciso que o formulário de contato seja enviado pra 2 e-mails diferentes, o código PHP está funcionando certinho, só preciso saber onde inserir o 2º e-mail de destino:

```html
<?php
 
 
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$idade = $_POST['idade'];
$inst = $_POST['instituto'];
$imersao = $_POST['imersao'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$fone = $_POST['fone'];
$facebook = $_POST['facebook'];
$cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
$msg = $_POST['mensagem'];
 
 
$headers = "From: ". $nome;
 
$corpoemail = 'Contato Via site
             
               Nome: '   .$nome.' 
               Idade: '   .$idade.' 
               Como conheceu o Instituto: '   .$inst.'
               Já fez nossa Imersão: '   .$imersao.'
               Email: '   .$email.'
               Fone: ' .$fone.' 
               Facebook: ' .$facebook.'
               Cidade: ' .$cidade.'
               Mensagem: '.$msg.' ';
 
 
 
 
if(mail("primeiro-email@provedor.com", "Cadastro Via Site",$corpoemail,$headers)){
 
 
       echo "<script>alert('Cadastro enviado com sucesso!');document.location='index.php';</script>";
 
} else{
 
      echo "<script>alert('Erro ao enviar, tente diretamente pelo primeiro-email@provedor.com');</script>";  
 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adiciona o segundo destinatário seperando por ","

```
   if(mail("primeiro-email@provedor.com, segundo-email@provedor.com",...
```

Para deixar um pouco mais elegante e facilitar manutenções posteriores, utilize variáveis para seus parâmetros.

```
<?php


$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$idade = $_POST['idade'];
$inst = $_POST['instituto'];
$imersao = $_POST['imersao'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$fone = $_POST['fone'];
$facebook = $_POST['facebook'];
$cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
$msg = $_POST['mensagem'];

$destino = "primeiro-email@provedor.com, segundo-email@provedor.com";
$assunto = "Cadastro Via Site";


$headers = "From: ". $nome;
/* Outra alternativa é adicionar através do header como cópia */
/* $headers .= "\r\n" . 'Cc: segundo-email@provedor.com' . "\r\n"; */

$corpoemail = 'Contato Via site

           Nome: '   .$nome.' 
           Idade: '   .$idade.' 
           Como conheceu o Instituto: '   .$inst.'
           Já fez nossa Imersão: '   .$imersao.'
           Email: '   .$email.'
           Fone: ' .$fone.' 
           Facebook: ' .$facebook.'
           Cidade: ' .$cidade.'
           Mensagem: '.$msg.' ';




if(mail($destino, $assunto, $corpoemail, $headers)){


   echo "<script>alert('Cadastro enviado com sucesso!');document.location='index.php';</script>";

} else{

      echo "<script>alert('Erro ao enviar, tente diretamente pelo primeiro-email@provedor.com');</script>";  

}
```

Comment: Fiz vários testes, com vários e-mails diferentes, o formulário só chega para o 1º e-mail...

Comment: Pouco provável, mas pode ser uma limitação do seu servidor de e-mails para evitar spam

Comment: @Clayton, você pode tentar adicionar o CC ou BCC no header

Comment: o código é exatamente ali como está no comentário?

Comment: @Clayton a princípio sim.

Comment: Realmente deve ser alguma coisa no servidor de hospedagem, pois no e-mail principal está aparecendo que foi enviado uma cópia ( CC ) para o segundo e-mail, porém o segundo e-mail não recebe...